# Xcode: How to change the format of one ViewController and have them all change

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, duplicates, viewcontroller

How would I set it if I have one main view controller and whenever I add another view controller to main.storyboard, it would have the exact same content and objects as the first one?  Essentially, how would I be duplicating ViewControllers without having to build them again?

```
 labelTime.text = @"Hello";
 labelTime.text = @"Help Would be Appreciated";
 labelTime.text = @"Thaaanks ";
```

Comment: In addition to subclassing, you can copy and paste view controller scenes in the storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the main.storyboard, you would click on the ViewController you want inherited from the class and then assign the Viewcontroller to the class.  ViewControllers are referred to by their Storyboard ID, so in the main.storyboard you could change it there.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the documentation of using Inheritance [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/objective_c/objective_c_inheritance.htm)  which allows us to define a class in terms of another class which makes it easier to create and maintain an application. This also provides an opportunity to reuse the code functionality and fast implementation time.

When creating a class, instead of writing completely new data members and member functions, the programmer can designate that the new class should inherit the members of an existing class. This existing class is called the base class, and the new class is referred to as the derived class.